# I keep getting ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: error. For some reason in cannot convert string into int

Tags: python

```
FILE_NAME = 'last_seen.txt'
def read_last_seen(FILE_NAME):
    file_read = open(FILE_NAME, 'r')
    last_seen_id = int(file_read.read().strip())
    file_read.close()
    return last_seen_id
id = read_last_seen(FILE_NAME)
print(id)
```

It says there is an error in line 20. I am trying to write a code for twitter mention, which is identified by a numeric id. However, I keep getting this error.

Comment: last_seen_id = int(file_read.read().strip())

Comment: Can you paste what is the content of file_read.read() ?

Comment: for "1264155962329272322 hey @mentions", the contents would be 1264155962329272322

Comment: It didn't work. It says, "IndexError: list index out of range"

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm being unclear. I'm very new to Python. I'll try my best to be clear. So, I'm trying to build a twitter bot using Tweepy. I'm trying to use the "mention" function which will allow the bot to identify mentioned tweets. The last_seen_id should contain numeric value like 1264155962329272322 , but for some reason it cannot convert that value.

Answer (score 1):

Okay. This is embarrassing.

After hours of trying to figure it out, I deleted the text file, created a new one.

Somehow the code couldn't access the text file. So, deleting it and creating a new text file did it for me!

Answer (score 0):

`file_read.read().strip()` is returning something that is not a valid base 10 number. So, when you try to convert it with `int()`, you get the error.

Without knowing the contents of your file it is difficult to give a complete answer. You could try wrapping it in a try-catch block:

```
try:
    last_seen_id = int(file_read.read().strip())
except ValueError:
    # You could log the error or provide a backup value
```

You could also validate your input before attempting to cast it to an integer.

Comment: Do not concatenate too much functions there. If you move the read line above the `try`, you can print its contents in the `except`. Then it will tell the OP *exactly* why the conversion is not working, rather than their current rather useless "there is an error in line 20".

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm being unclear. I'm very new to Python. I'll try my best to be clear. So, I'm trying to build a twitter bot using Tweepy. I'm trying to use the "mention" function which will allow the bot to identify mentioned tweets. The last_seen_id should contain numeric value like 1264155962329272322 , but for some reason it cannot convert that value.

Comment: @usr2564301 Sure, that's what I was referring to when I mentioned validating the inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming last_text.txt has following content:

```
1
2
3
```

Without any try-except:

```
def read_last_seen(file_name):
    # Read file and split by newline
    with open(file_name, 'r') as fh:
        data = fh.read().split('\n')

    # Remove empty lines from list
    data = list(filter(None, data))

    # Return last line
    return int(data[-1])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    file_name = 'last_seen.txt'
    id = read_last_seen(file_name)
    print(id)
```

Ofcourse it would be better to check before hand if file_name exists and check if the id can be converted to int.

Comment: It gives an "IndexError: list index out of range" error

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm being unclear. I'm very new to Python. I'll try my best to be clear. So, I'm trying to build a twitter bot using Tweepy. I'm trying to use the "mention" function which will allow the bot to identify mentioned tweets. The last_seen_id should contain numeric value like 1264155962329272322 , but for some reason it cannot convert that value.

Comment: @JubinKc         Storing 1264155962329272322 as integer is no problem. I believe the problem is how you read the content of the file. Can you post a sample "last_seen.txt" file with which the problem occurs? Would be much easier to debug.

Comment: It simply stores the integer as 1264218956618858497. I think the data couldn't store itself in the last_seen.txt file. So, I deleted the old file and created a new file with the same name. As a intial value, I put "1234567890123456789" manually, Then the code worked.